# Is it necessary to add hyphens before this location?

Tags: grammaticality-in-context, hyphens, locative

I am wondering whether I need to add hyphens to **Karala** in this context? Is it necessary?

Moreover, this specific education allows her to aid like no other to her home region **--Karala**, whose population is experiencing serious difficulties as a consequence of climate change. Intensive droughts, natural resource overexploitation, and minor governmental regulation have led to a decrease in biodiversity and water resources available for the people to survive

Comment: _Moreover, this specific education allows her to aid like no other to her home region of Karala, [...]_ __or__ _Moreover, this specific education allows her to aid like no other to her home region, Karala, [...]_ __or__ _Moreover, this specific education allows her to aid like no other to her home region--Karala-- [...]_

Comment: Put the same mark on both sides of *Karala*, either comma or dash.

Comment: "Double hyphens" is not an actual punctiation mark. `--` is sometimes used in informal contexts to substitute a dash when your keyboard does not let you input dash easily.